# jQuery Duplicate Table row and assign new id to duplicate table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, clone

I have created a table with multiple columns and written a jquery javascript that duplicates or clones the the last row of the table. However when it clones the last row it also gives each column the same name and id as the previous row.

jsp code:

```
<div id="invTruck" class="invTruck">
            <table id="tbl_invTruck" width="100%"  border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="15%" style="display:none;"><center>Work Order Id</center></td>
                    <td width="17%"><center>Truck Type</center></td>
                    <td width="17%"><center>Licences Plate #</center></td>
                    <td width="17%"><center>Driver ID</center></td>
                    <td width="17%"><center>Max Haulage Weight</center></td>
                    <td width="17%"><center>Job Number</center></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="display:none;"><input name="wInv_work_Id" type="text"></td>
                    <td><select id="invTru_Type" name="invTru_Type" onchange="getTruckPlates(this.value)">
                        <option disabled selected hidden value="">Select A Truck Type</option>
                        <%while(rsinvTru1.next()){%>
                         <option><%=rsinvTru1.getString(1)%></option>
                        <%}%>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><select id="invTru_LicensePlateNo" name="invTru_LicensePlateNo" required>
                        <option disabled selected hidden value="">Select A Truck</option>

                        </select></td>
                    <td><input name="driver_emp_Id" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input name="invTru_MaxHw" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input name="" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table width="100%" height="50%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%"><input class="buttonCreateInv" id="btn_AddTruck" type="button"  value="Add A Truck"></td>
                    <td width="50%"><input class="buttonCreateInv" name="btn_RemoveTruck" type="button" value="Remove A Truck"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
```

JQuery Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_AddTruck").click(function(){
       var $tableBody = $('#tbl_invTruck').find("tbody"),
        $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
        $trNew = $trLast.clone();

    $trLast.after($trNew); 

    });
});
```

The expected output i would like is for the duplicated table row
 
where id in id1 is the orignal tables td id and 1 is appended to it.
and that if i was to add another row to the table

where id in id2 is the orignal tables td id and 2 is appended to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try next one:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn_AddTruck").click(function () {
               var $tableBody = $('#tbl_invTruck').find("tbody"),
                $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
                $trNew = $trLast.clone();
                // Find by attribute 'id'
                $trNew.find('[id]').each(function () {
                    var num = this.id.replace(/\D/g, '');
                    if (!num) {
                        num = 0;
                    }
                    // Remove numbers by first regexp
                    this.id = this.id.replace(/\d/g, '') 
                        // increment number
                        + (1 + parseInt(num, 10));
                });
        
                $trLast.after($trNew); 
        
            });
        });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="invTruck" class="invTruck">
                <table id="tbl_invTruck" width="100%"  border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15%" style="display:none;"><center>Work Order Id</center></td>
                        <td width="17%"><center>Truck Type</center></td>
                        <td width="17%"><center>Licences Plate #</center></td>
                        <td width="17%"><center>Driver ID</center></td>
                        <td width="17%"><center>Max Haulage Weight</center></td>
                        <td width="17%"><center>Job Number</center></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="display:none;"><input name="wInv_work_Id" type="text"></td>
                        <td><select id="invTru_Type" name="invTru_Type" onchange="getTruckPlates(this.value)">
                            <option disabled selected hidden value="">Select A Truck Type</option>
                            <!-- %while(rsinvTru1.next()){%>
                             <option><%=rsinvTru1.getString(1)%></option>
                            <%}% -->
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><select id="invTru_LicensePlateNo" name="invTru_LicensePlateNo" required>
                            <option disabled selected hidden value="">Select A Truck</option>

                            </select></td>
                        <td><input name="driver_emp_Id" type="text"></td>
                        <td><input name="invTru_MaxHw" type="text"></td>
                        <td><input name="" type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" height="50%" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%"><input class="buttonCreateInv" id="btn_AddTruck" type="button"  value="Add A Truck"></td>
                        <td width="50%"><input class="buttonCreateInv" name="btn_RemoveTruck" type="button" value="Remove A Truck"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: i tried this method however it did not change the clone id i got NaN thanks for this solution your time and effort is greatly appreciated

Comment: i tried your jquery solution but it sets the id of the clones row to NaN. Your time and effort is greatly appreciated Thank you so much

Comment: Just do not forget to remove `!--` and `--` for a while section

Comment: Hi so i am now trying for each of the ids in the table row to be incremented by 1 can you assist with that. The code you provided only increments the select boxes by 1. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much please disregard last i have been coding for about 36 hours now without sleep and forget id not give my fields any ids.

Comment: Everything is fine, take care of yourself. And, yes, only existing IDs will be incremented. P.S. You could mark the question as resolved by ✓ or extend it if needed :)